# Hydropower Calculation

Tags: grass-gis, hydrology

I have assigned the elevation and the volume flow to each point at a river (with `v.to.db` and `v.what.rast`). Now I want to calculate the Elevation difference between each pair of points and then calculate the Hydropower between them by using `P=density * Q * delta_h * g`. 
Here you can see an example of my Attribute Table (I know the differences are too small but it is only an example):

[image]

I don't know how to do this. Is there a way in GRASS or how can I realize that?

---

OK, I know how to Calculate the Hydropower with given Elevation difference (SQL Builder (Update) -> Field Calculator)).
It works fine to multiply different rows. But one step is in my opinion not feasible with that:
To Calculate the differences between Elevation as shown above (I cannot say something like: Elevation=i+1 - Elevation=i). Is there another Way?

Maybe to calculate it directly in GRASS and not in the Attribute table?

Comment: Nobody can tell me? Or is it the wrong way to calculate the Hydropower?

Comment: Just take this table to excel and calculate the difference -